# Hiding the incoming phone number using an custom dialer feature

Tags: android, android-support-library

I have a plan to make a dialing feature to hide the caller's ID. I have an application with the caller's phone number embedded in the "Dial" button.

In the application the both parties (caller and receiver) can see their own numbers.

I use the following code for the default call:

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(“tel:”+mNumberEditText.getText().toString()));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

My problem is to hide both parties' numbers. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: You cannot do this until you have your application which supports call feature , If you are using base android dialer , you  never know if the call was triggered from your application on the recevier end . There is no using of hiding the number if you are using base android dialer , because the number gets listed in call log as well.

Comment: Can't we make a custom dial-er for this on top of android dial-er and the call is ended when we remove the particular number from the call log.

Comment: Yes , we can do that  query your app database or fetch number from the server if the number belongs to your app you need an overlay as TrueCaller doe , and delete the calllog entry  with required permission,